# How to do unit test for spring boot auto configuration

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot

In a spring boot auto configuration project there are two emailSender child classes: MockEmailSender and TextEmailSender. And in auto configuration only one mailSender should be created：

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(MailSender.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="spring.mail.host", havingValue="foo", matchIfMissing=true)
public MailSender mockMailSender() {

    log.info("Configuring MockMailSender");       
    return new MockMailSender();
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(MailSender.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty("spring.mail.host")
public MailSender smtpMailSender(JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {

    log.info("Configuring SmtpMailSender");       
    return new SmtpMailSender(javaMailSender);
}
```

following is my unit test code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class LemonTest implements ApplicationContextAware{
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(LemonTest.class, args);
        System.out.println("haha");
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.context = applicationContext;
    }
}


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class InitTest {
    @Autowired
    private MailSender mailSender;

    @Test
    public void test(){
        assertNotNull(mailSender);
    }
}
```

And the properties are

```
spring.mail.host=foo
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=alert1
spring.mail.password=123456
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
```

Based on my auto configuration only MockEmailSender should be initialized, 
but both emailSender bean are created, so multiple bean error is thrown when running the unit test. I guess my configuration settings are not loaded by the test.

So how to include the auto configuration in the test? what would be the best practices to test auto configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve it. Just add `@Import(LemonAutoConfiguration.class)` to the application.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(LemonAutoConfiguration.class)
public class LemonTest implements ApplicationContextAware{
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(LemonTest.class, args);
        System.out.println("haha");
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.context = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Somebody downvoted, but this did the trick for me, for a not-spring autoconfigure Configuration

Answer (score 0):

I've always created multiple tests using separate "profiles" to control what is loaded/set, setting the active profile on the test.

```
@ActiveProfiles({ "test", "multipleemail" })
```

Then your test would ensure the expected result (multiple email providers in context, etc).
Properties can be imported if you need separate ones. I store one in src/test specifically for my unit tests.

```
@PropertySource({ "classpath:sparky.properties" })
```

Comment: no matter which profile to use, there should be one emailSender because I used `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(MailSender.class)` in my auto configuration.